# How to create an audience of users that were active in the past, but not in the past week

Tags: firebase-analytics

I want to send messages to users who were active in the past but inactive in the last 7 days. I am trying to create an audience that targets users who have NOT completed the event X in the LAST 7 DAYS, but they HAD completed it at some point in the past. Because there is no "last N days" condition to exclude, I am unable to create this audience. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

According to the blog post on [A Crash Course in Using the New Audiences in Analytics](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/a-crash-course-in-using-new-audiences.html), it **is** possible to exclude groups from dynamic audiences these days. See the section on <kbd>Excluding Groups</kbd> in the post.

So you'll need two groups:

1. Users that were ever active
2. Users that were active in the past week

And then you build your final audience of users that are in group 1, but not in group 2.

An example of this (again from the blog post):

[image]

The above screenshot creates an audience of users who *did* exercise at least 5 times, but *did not* track a meal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what you did there, but what if I want both conditions to refer to the same event? ie. Users who completed the exercise at some point in the past, but did not complete that same exercise in the last 7 days? Active before/inactive recently. I read the article you shared (thanks for that too) and since my purpose is to target the audience with messages, I decided to customize the recipients by including an audience that had completed a request in the past, and excluding an audience who have been inactive in the last 7 days.

Comment: As far as I know having both conditions on the same property should work too.

Comment: How would you define the mentioned audience with users that were active in the last week? Create a custom audience with e.g `app_open > 0` and membership duration of 7 days? Selecting "in any seven day period" would mean "at some point since the creation of the universe there was a seven-day-period where the user performed an event x times", right?